# partitioning multiple list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to create a function that divides by the same number when there are multiple lists.Currently, only one list of functions can be created.In the function below, randint is changed due to the while loop, so multiple lists can not be divided into the same size. Also, the range of randint is applied, but it is more difficult to know which number comes first.
I want to modify it in the function. The reason is because random size list comes out. I really appreciate it if you let me know

```
def random_chunk(a, min_chunk=1, max_chunk=5):
    it = iter(a)
    while True:
        nxt = list(islice(it,randint(min_chunk,max_chunk)))
        if nxt:
            yield nxt
        else:
            break

# It is an example I want.
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8,9,10]
c = [11,12,13,14,15] 


k = list(random_chunk(a))
b = list(random_chunk(b))
c = list(random_chunk(c))


#print
[[1,2],[3],[4,5]] <- a
[[6,7],[8],[9,10]] <- b 
[[11,12],[13],[14,15]] <- c

or
[[1,2,3],[4],[5]]
[[6,7,8],[9],[10]]
[[11,12,13],[14],[15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move your `randint` outside the while loop by assigning it to a variable:

```
def random_chunk(a, min_chunk=1, max_chunk=5):
    it = iter(a)
    chunk_size = randint(min_chunk,max_chunk)
    while True:
        nxt = list(islice(it,chunk_size))
        if nxt:
            yield nxt
        else:
            break
```

Comment: I've tried like you. But the list size is different.

Comment: It's not very clear where your problem is. If you want to split multiple lists into random sized chunks but have each list be split in the same way as every other list, then you are better off defining the random sizes first, then splitting each list in a for loop.